# Use google-api-nodejs-client in Angular 7 app

Tags: angular, google-api-nodejs-client

I'd like to use google-api-nodejs-client (https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis) in my WebApplication. I wanted to move whole Google logic from backend to frontend. 
However, I get the issue:

> ERROR in ./node_modules/gtoken/node_modules/mime/index.js Module not
>   found: Error: Can't resolve './types/other' in
>   '...\node_modules\gtoken\node_modules\mime' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/gtoken/node_modules/mime/index.js Module not found:
>   Error: Can't resolve './types/standard' in
>   '...\node_modules\gtoken\node_modules\mime' ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js Module
>   not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in
>   '...\node_modules\google-auth-library\build\src\auth'

It's obviouse that child_process is not available on Browser side. But is it possible to use that library to manipulate with calendar from WebApp? Or is there any other library which can be used instead google-api-nodejs-client?

I see that there is version 37.0.0-webapp but I'm not sure how can I use it in my Typescript Angular project.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Can you give this a try with version 37?  We updated a few underlying libraries so theoretically this should all work now :) Let me know on the issue tracker if you run into issues!

Comment: I found that googleauth required child_process which in not available for Browsers

Comment: With the latest version?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
npm install --save @types/node
```